# is there a word to represent once every nine months

Tags: single-word-requests

is there a single word to represent "once every nine months"?
Since 9 months is a fraction larger than half a year, semi-annualy seems wrong.

Comment: You could always try [***tri-trimesterally***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimester). What's the real-world context where you might need such a term?

Comment: Semi-annual (or biannual) is certainly wrong. I think you need to coin something. I like FumbleFingers' **tri-trimesteral**, but would add two more possibilities, **nonamesteral** and **sesquibiannual**.

Comment: If you want something that people will actually understand, you can stick with "9-month period".  Anything else could be confusing, IMO. (FumbleFingers Tri-Tri... sounds a lot like stuttering to me! lol!)

Comment: @KristinaLopez That is a fair point, although for the *frequency* the OP is looking for they'd still have to put something like their "once every" before it.

Comment: every three quarters in economics; quarterly; bi-annually, every three quarters or every third quarter;

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps consider *dodranial* or perhaps *dodrantal*, formed from the Latin *[dodrans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodrans)*.  Of *dodrans*, Wikipedia says:

> The Latin word literally means nine-twelfths, and can refer to a time span of forty-five minutes or a length of nine inches.

Note, ignore the claim at [languagehat/dodrans](http://languagehat.com/dodrans/) that *dodrans* means 2/3; a comment later in the page substantiates that *dodrans* is 3/4, while *bes* is 2/3.  Also, [phrontistery](http://phrontistery.info/clw1.html) has an OED-based entry for *dodrantal*:

> adj   1656-1883 of nine inches in length

Comment: I'd coin a word: Dodrennial. But hell yeah.

Answer (score 1):

trimester = trimestris = tres + mensis = 3 months

semester = semestris = sex + mensis = 6 months

So wouldn't it be nomester = nomestris = novem + mensis = 9 months